# Поиск простых чисел в матрице

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Начал изучение C++. Нашел такую задачу: поиск простых чисел в матрице. У меня получается что находит нечетные числа. А нужны простые. Помогите доделать прогу.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[10][10], i, j, n;

    do {
        cout << "Размер матрицы: ";
        cin >> n;
    } while (n < 3 || n > 3); // Определяю размер матрицы

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            cout << "a(" << i << "," << j << ")=";
            cin >> a[i][j]; // Ввожу элементы матрицы
        }
    }

    cout << "Матрица:";
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cout << "\n";
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            cout << a[i][j] << " "; //Вывод элементов матрицы
        }
    }

    cout << "\nПростые числа: ";
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if ((a[i][j] % 2)) {
                cout << a[i][j] << " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы вспомните определение простого числа:)

Comment: 1. написать  функцию, проверяющую  число на простоту(в этом сайте много таких примеров).      2.  Применить функцию к каждому элементу матрицы, при возвращении истины, увеличить счетчик.

Comment: посмотрите алгоритмы в интернете, а для начала лучше сами постарайтесь написать какой нибудь алгоритм, а поиск в матрице, массиве или просто число дано на простоту проверить, разницы ведь нет

Comment: `n < 3 || n > 3` Я что, на выборах?

Answer (score -4):

можно просто каждое число проверять на простоту еще одним циклом:

```
    int flag = 0;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
        flag = 0;
        for(k=2; k<=(int)sqrt(a[i][j]); k++){
            if((a[i][j] % k)) {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0) cout << a[i][j] << " ";

    }
}
```

только не забудь cmath подключить для корня